# how to remember the last path when insert files into Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

i have application with Listbox and files, each time i press on Add button the default C drive open and i want the application to remember the last path i used

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Stream myStream;
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    thisDialog.Filter = "(*.snoop, *.pcap, *.cap, *.net)|*.snoop; *.pcap; *.cap; *.net|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true; // Allow the user to select multiple files
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File";
    thisDialog.FileName = lastPath;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the last directory used in a global variable like this:

```
private string _lastPath = string.Empty;
```

then after the file selection initialize it:

```
if(thisDialog.Filenames.Length > 0)
    _lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.Filenames[0]);
```

when you reopen the dialog set the InitialDirectory with this check:

```
thisDialog.InitialDirectory = (_lastPath.Length > 0 ? _lastPath: "c:\\");
```

and remove the thisDialog.FileName = lastPath;

EDIT --- UPDATE OF YOUR CODE ---

```
// This at the global level of your form 
private string _lastPath = string.Empty;**

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    System.IO.Stream myStream; 
    OpenFileDialog thisDialog = new OpenFileDialog(); 
    thisDialog.InitialDirectory = (_lastPath.Length > 0 ? _lastPath: "c:\\");
    thisDialog.Filter = "(*.snoop, *.pcap, *.cap, *.net)|*.snoop; *.pcap; *.cap; *.net|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
    thisDialog.FilterIndex = 1; 
    thisDialog.RestoreDirectory = false; 
    thisDialog.Multiselect = true; // Allow the user to select multiple files 
    thisDialog.Title = "Please Select Source File"; 
    thisDialog.FileName = lastPath; 
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); 

    if (thisDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        if(thisDialog.Filenames.Length > 0) 
            _lastPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(thisDialog.Filenames[0]);

        foreach (String file in thisDialog.FileNames) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                if ((myStream = thisDialog.OpenFile()) != null) 
                { 
                    using (myStream) 
                    { 
                        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(file); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 

            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message); 
            } 
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: can you please show me example on my code where to put it ? (it didn't work for me)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Visual Studio have the last path value for every execution of the application.

Only have to go to Project Properties->Configuration and add a value descriptor.

Example:

Name = LastPath; Type = string; Scope = User; Value = "Default path";

And then after you rebuild yout application, you can set this property this way:

```
Settings.Default.LastPath = LastPathSelected;
```

later, you can retrieve the value with:

```
thisDialog.InitialDirectory = Settings.Default.LastPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
thisDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(lastPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory property. Note: you are setting the directory and not the file. So be sure to remove the filename from the path.

[more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

remove this line and you have the last path

```
thisDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
```